# str_replace function doesn't work to replace character from a user inputted data

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, str-replace

I have a user inputted description in my textarea. The description inputted value looks like this when assigned to a variable `<p style="text-align:center;">user inputted description text</p>` since I am using a rich text editor as my textarea. I want to replace the character `"` with a space using the `str_replace('"', ' ',$course_desc);` However, when saved, the value for course_desc in the database when stored is only `<p style=`. Seems the character `"` wasn't replace. But when I just declare my own variable with the same kind of description `<p style="text-align:center;">user inputted description text</p>` and not based on the user input, the character `"` was correctly replaced with space. What is the problem with this? Here is my code:

Model.php (variable `$course_desc` value was came from user inputted data)

```
public function insert_file($filename,$course_name,$course_desc,$tennant_email,$is_public,$concat_url)
 {

  $course_desc_replace = str_replace('"', ' ',$course_desc);

  $data = array(
     'course_id'     => '',
     'tennant_id'    => $tennant_email,
     'display_public'=> $is_public,
     'course_name'   => $course_name,
     'course_desc'   => $course_desc_replace,
     'private_url'   => $concat_url,
     'filename'      => $filename

              );

        $this->db->insert('courses', $data);
         return true;
 }
```

course_desc field value in the database table is:

```
<p style=
```

Model.php (variable `$sample` value didn't came from a user input)

```
public function insert_file($filename,$course_name,$course_desc,$tennant_email,$is_public,$concat_url)
 {


$sample = '<p style="text-align:center;">sample</p>';
$course_desc_replace = str_replace('"', ' ',$sample);

  $data = array(
     'course_id'     => '',
     'tennant_id'    => $tennant_email,
     'display_public'=> $is_public,
     'course_name'   => $course_name,
     'course_desc'   => $course_desc_replace,
     'private_url'   => $concat_url,
     'filename'      => $filename

              );

        $this->db->insert('courses', $data);
         return true;
   }
```

course_desc field value in the database table is:

```
<p style= text-align:center; >text</p>
```

Comment: _Why_ do you want to get rid of quotation marks `""` ?? Something indicates you try to solve a problem, and now just have got another problem ..

Comment: use [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for the output .. and the `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be different types of quotation marks causing the problem? There's a few different types:

```
"   U+0022 QUOTATION MARK
“   U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
”   U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
```

**Edit -** Many more similar ones actually! Check this link, there's about 15:
http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=%22&r=None

Comment: so, if this is the case,how would I set up the str_replace?